# SimpMessagingTemplate not sending messages in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp

Hi all I am trying to send messages to Stomp Endpoints but I not getting any.I am using spring boot with stomp following are my classes

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  @MessageMapping("/hello")
  @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
  public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(message.getName());
    Thread.sleep(13000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
  }

}

@Controller                                                
public class Testcont {

  @Autowired
  private SimpMessagingTemplate messageSender;

  @RequestMapping(value="/Users/get",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String getUser(@RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password, @RequestParam(value="port") String port, HttpServletRequest request) {
    HelloMessage mess=new HelloMessage();
    mess.setName(userId);
    messageSender.convertAndSend("/app/hello",mess);
    return "Success";

}
```

and my Configuration for websocket

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I am not getting any errors in consoles .the above code is working great with web browsers .

Comment: How did u achieve this Zahid? m stuck on same issue and i couldn't understand the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `SimpMessagingTemplate` bean is exactly for the Broker part (`AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration`):

```
@Bean
public SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate() {
    SimpMessagingTemplate template = new SimpMessagingTemplate(brokerChannel());
    String prefix = getBrokerRegistry().getUserDestinationPrefix();
    if (prefix != null) {
        template.setUserDestinationPrefix(prefix);
    }
```

Since you send message not to the broker destination (`/app/` in your case), such a message is just ignored by the `AbstractBrokerMessageHandler.checkDestinationPrefix(destination)`.

If you'd like to handle that internal message by the same `@MessageMapping`, you should use the `clientInboundChannel` directly, which is supplied by the `SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler`:

```
@Bean
public SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler simpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler() {
    SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler handler = createAnnotationMethodMessageHandler();
    handler.setDestinationPrefixes(getBrokerRegistry().getApplicationDestinationPrefixes());
```

I guess you can create your own `SimpMessagingTemplate` instance for the `clientInboundChannel`, similar to that `brokerMessagingTemplate` bean. And you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks I think I now know where I am making mistake .

Comment: Artem I didn't understood ur answer, can u guide me?

Comment: Not sure from where you guide, but I think that really would be better to start from the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html. Everything rest should be addressed in the separate SO thread.

Comment: i have read the doc and my code is exactly same except template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", text); according to the spring doc, but it is not giving error and neither my websocket is called. the question is prety much same so if i do it in serprate thread il be baned from asking question

Comment: As I said: please, raise a new SO question with particular info and will try to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919790/simpmessagingtemplate-not-sending-messages-to-websocket please check this

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue and the answer and follow up questions are not clear.

Answer (score 8):

I face the same problem when working on WebSocket. It is too later for this post, but may be useful for who are looking for the answer.

SimpMessagingTemplate -> work with "topic" not "app"
So 
messageSender.convertAndSend("/topic/hello",mess); will be a solution.

From WebSocket doc mentioned above:

"clientInboundChannel" — for passing messages received from WebSocket clients.

"clientOutboundChannel" — for sending server messages to WebSocket clients.

"brokerChannel" — for sending messages to the message broker from within server-side, application code.

1. Client connects to "http://localhost:8080/portfolio" and once a WebSocket connection is established, STOMP frames begin to flow on it. ( in your case:
   registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS(), you use "hello", in the doc, it used "portfolio".)
2. Client sends SUBSCRIBE frame with destination header "/topic/hello". Once received and decoded, the message is sent to the "clientInboundChannel", then routed to the message broker which stores the client subscription. (This is UI subscribed to WebSocket, you don't have codes about it here. That's fine.)
3. Client sends SEND frame to "/app/hello". The "/app" prefix helps to route it to annotated controllers. After the "/app" prefix is stripped, the remaining "/hello" part of the destination is mapped to the @MessageMapping method in GreetingController. ( in your codes : @MessageMapping("/hello") will receive the frame. )
4. The value returned from GreetingController is turned into a Spring Message with a payload based on the return value and a default destination header of "/topic/hello" (derived from the input destination with "/app" replaced by "/topic"). The resulting message is sent to the "brokerChannel" and handled by the message broker. **( So when you try to put data in WebSocket in the server: messageSender.convertAndSend("/app/hello",mess); should be changed to messageSender.convertAndSend("/topic/hello",mess), because it is already in the server, we don't need destination prefix, but we need broker prefix.)**
5. The message broker finds all matching subscribers, and sends a MESSAGE frame to each through the "clientOutboundChannel" from where messages are encoded as STOMP frames and sent on the WebSocket connection.