# SimpMessagingTemplate not sending messages to websocket

Tags: spring-websocket

I have the following contoller

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController 
{
        @MessageMapping("/hello")
        @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
        public Person greeting(String message) throws Exception {
                Person person=new Person();
                person.setAge(10);
                return person;
        }
        @Autowired
        private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

        @RequestMapping(path="/meeting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public  @ResponseBody void greet() {
            this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "message");
         }
    }
```

and my configuration is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig1 extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

So according to spring doc template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "message") should call the broker and the mapped web socket will be called.

Code for front-end using SockJS

```
var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
                     stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
                     stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                         console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                         stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                             console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body));

                         });
    // to send via the web service-WORKING ( but websocket not called in springs)
     $.post("http://localhost:8080/meeting");

    // to send via websocket - WORKING
    stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'message':'message'}));
```

There are no errors in the console. I can connect it through SockJs and send message to "/topic/greetings" but i want to call a webService which in return calls the web Socket. So after searching alot i m stuck cause there are no errors and cant find a different way to do it in spring.

Comment: Be sure that your clients are subscribed to the `/topic/greetings`. Otherwise there is nothing on the server side to send message to.

Comment: I make connection and subscribe to the client using sockjs. And m able to even send it using sockjs. But if I call web service /meeting from postman after I made connection in sockjs nothing happens

Comment: Well, not sure how to help you. Everything looks good. I Spring Integration we have a similar test-case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-stomp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/stomp/inbound/StompInboundChannelAdapterWebSocketIntegrationTests.java. The `StompInboundChannelAdapter` does a `subscribeDestination(destination);` and there is exactly `messagingTemplate.send("/topic/myTopic",`. So, please, investigate DEBUG logs of your application or just debug your `greet()` method up to the Spring source code

Comment: Maybe your `HelloMessage` just can't be converted properly to `byte[]` for sending. See `AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration.brokerMessageConverter()`

Comment: @AfrozShaikh Did you figure this out?

Comment: The javascript code in the description is incomplete, so I am not sure. Are you calling the `$.post` method after the `stompClient.connect`´s callback is executed? Have you tried to put breakpoints in the browser to check that the callback is actually executed before the $.post?

Comment: @AfrozShaikh how did you resolve this? I have same issue, annotation works but not via the messaging template

Comment: @AfrozShaikh your code is perfect. Only one thing you can try is try removing ResponseBody from your greet() method.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and instead of sending simple string you should send object
so instead of

```
this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "message");
```

should be

`this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", messageObject);`

and your object should have some method to access content
like

```
MessageObject.getConent();
```

otherwise you can always use `toString()`

and your js should be

```js
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
    console.log(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
});
```

notice content on the end of received object